# Image swapping using JQuery on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace an image with another using jQuery in JavaScript. Its an online bus reservation website. So when clicked on an available image it should change into unavailable image. Does anyone know about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#myImage').on('click', function(e) {
    var image = this;
    img.src = '/path/to/another/image.png';
});
```

Also, if you have a bunch of images that need to be swapped, it's better to use event delegation. Let's assume that these swappable images can be anywhere on the page, and you assign a `swappable` class to all of them. You can then set up just one event handler to handle the swapping, even if you dynamically add new images with AJAX:

```
$(document).on('click', 'img.swappable', function(e) {
    var image = this;
    image.src = getAvailableImageUrl();
});
```

Comment: What advantage does your code hold over this: `$('#myImg').click(function(){this.src="path/to/img.png"});`?

Comment: jQuery has recommended the use of .on() for binding events, so I'm just using that convention. This way, the syntax is very similar if I want to use event delegation, e.g. `$('body').on('click', 'img.swappable', ...);`

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways, Here are some.

```
<img id="bannerLogo" src="/path/to/image/logoup.png" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var imageCounter = 0;
$('#bannerLogo').click(function(){
    if(imageCounter%2==0){
        $('#bannerLogo').attr('src', '/path/to/image/logodown.png');
    }
    else {
        $('#bannerLogo').attr('src', '/path/to/image/logoup.png');
    }
    imageCounter++;
});
</script>
```

Or

(Note - As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().)

```
<img class="swapper" src="imagename_off.jpg"  />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $(".swapper").live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "swapper") {
      this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
    } else {
      this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
  });
});
</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Ill also add in my hover script, just in case you need it at some point:

```
$('#bannerLogo').hover(
      function() { $('#bannerLogo').attr('src', '/path/logodown.png');}, 
      function() { $('#bannerLogo').attr('src', '/path/logoup.png'); 
});
```

Don't forget to include JQuery lib

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()`  to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()`  in preference to `.live()`.

Comment: No prob, glad I could help.
Did it work out for you in the end? It works fine for me